# Image size too small when loading SVG with Glide

Tags: java, android, svg, android-glide

I'm using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images.

On my app, I'm using the following sample to load an SVG image into my `ImageView` that is inside a `CardView`.

```
GenericRequestBuilder<Uri, InputStream, SVG, PictureDrawable> requestBuilder;

requestBuilder = Glide.with(mContext)
        .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, mContext), InputStream.class)
        .from(Uri.class)
        .as(SVG.class)
        .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
        .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
        .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<>(new SVGDecoder()))
        .decoder(new SVGDecoder())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.modulo)
        .error(R.drawable.banner_error)
        .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
        .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());

requestBuilder
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .load(Uri.parse("http://foo.bar/blah"))
        .into(cardHolder.iv_card);
```

The `ImageView` has a fixed width of `102dp` and a fixed height of `94dp` in the XML. But the images are getting smaller than they should after they are being loaded. Am I doing something wrong?

The scaleType is: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

[image: img_20160219_155824]

Comment: Did you set a scaleType property on the ImageView?

Comment: Yes, it's `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible this is related to [this AndroidSVG issue](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg/issues/79). I haven't had the time to investigate that bug report yet. Is it just `fitXY` mode where this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to open this question as [an issue on the libs repository](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/988), and then I was able to fix the problem.

As it turned out, the problem was related to my SVG having a fixed size, so to fix it I had to modify my `SvgDecoder.decode` method, and add those three lines:

```
svg.setDocumentWidth(width);
svg.setDocumentHeight(height);
svg.setDocumentPreserveAspectRatio(PreserveAspectRatio.STRETCH);
```

The method now looks like this:

```
public Resource<SVG> decode(InputStream source, int width, int height) throws IOException {
    try {
        SVG svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(source);

        svg.setDocumentWidth(width);
        svg.setDocumentHeight(height);
        svg.setDocumentPreserveAspectRatio(PreserveAspectRatio.STRETCH);

        return new SimpleResource<>(svg);
    } catch (SVGParseException ex) {
        throw new IOException("Cannot load SVG from stream.", ex);
    }
}
```

Now it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the accepted answer - for me solution didn't work, the reason behind this was no proper viewbox in svg

Adding

```
if (svg.documentViewBox == null)
svg.setDocumentViewBox(0f, 0f, svg.documentWidth, svg.documentHeight)
```

before changing svg width/height fixed scaling finally

Answer (score 1):

The unchecked answer helps me a lot!

he glide's API has changed and now my code looks like this:

SvgDecoder.java:

```
public Resource<SVG> decode(
        @NonNull InputStream source, int width, int height, @NonNull Options options)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        SVG svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(source);
        if (svg.getDocumentViewBox() == null)
            svg.setDocumentViewBox(0f, 0f, svg.getDocumentWidth(), svg.getDocumentHeight());

        if (width != SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
            svg.setDocumentWidth(width);
        }
        if (height != SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
            svg.setDocumentHeight(height);
        }
        return new SimpleResource<>(svg);
    } catch (SVGParseException ex) {
        throw new IOException("Cannot load SVG from stream", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this completely breaks any `scaleType` set on android `ImageView` or using methods from `Glide` itself. It was added to `SVGDecoder` in version `4.12` of the library examples.