# How to load svg image to image view using Glide

Tags: java, android, android-layout, svg, android-glide

I have a `SVG` image in this URL. [svg image link](https://restcountries.eu/data/zwe.svg)
. I want to load this `SVG` image from `url` into `image view`. I have used `Glide` to load this `SVG` image to `image view`.

**Here's the Glide Code:**

```
 Glide.with( context)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions().timeout(60000))
                .load( "https://restcountries.eu/data/zwe.svg" )
                .thumbnail( 0.5f )
                .override( 200, 200 )
                .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        flag_iv.setEnabled(true);
                        return false;
                    }

                })
                .into( flag_iv );
```

**XML Code:**

```
<ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/icon_app"
     android:id="@+id/flag_iv"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
 />
```

But it doesn't get loaded. It shows the below error.

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg with size [100x100]
```

I have used `png/jpg` images using `Glide`. It worked Great. Why `SVG` images are not loading using Glide. I searched Stack Overflow. Everyone suggesting different Libraries. But they are outdated. I want to achieve it using `Glide`. Please help me with some solutions.

Comment: It does not depend on Glide but on beeing an .svg image. An ImageView cannot display an .svg file.

Comment: @blackapps, Then how to display svg image in imageview. Any other solution?

Comment: 1. use this library: 
  -- implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.0") 
  -- implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.2.0")  --- 

Another way....
2. https://tech.fleka.me/how-to-load-svg-file-from-web-in-android-6cd2f4dc59b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Glide To Vector,

repo : https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou

and to load svg into imageview you can use:

```
GlideToVectorYou
                .init()
                .with(this)
                .withListener(new GlideToVectorYouListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Load failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Image ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                })
                .setPlaceHolder(placeholderLoading, placeholderError)
                .load(IMAGE_URL, imageview);
```

Comment: how can we use this in recycler adapter?

Comment: This works perfectly. Note: once you add this to your build.gradle you can simply use glide and it automatically works with SVGs now.

Answer (score 0):

By default `Glide` won't handle `SVG` image format. `SVG` is an `XML` based image format that requires parsing.

You can find an example from `Glide` at https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v4.10.0/samples/svg on how to create an `AppGlideModule` that registers `SVGDecoder` to perform that XML parsing.

Once that is in place (note you'll need `kapt` for kotlin or `annotationProcessor` for Java) you can use `Glide` the way you've used it in your code with a minimal of:

```
Glide.with(baseContext).load(svgPath).into(imageView)
```

### Example code

```
@GlideModule
class SvgModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry
            .register(SVG::class.java, PictureDrawable::class.java, SvgDrawableTranscoder())
            .append(InputStream::class.java, SVG::class.java, SvgDecoder())
    }

    // Disable manifest parsing to avoid adding similar modules twice.
    override fun isManifestParsingEnabled() = false
}
```

```
class SvgDecoder : ResourceDecoder<InputStream, SVG> {
    override fun handles(source: InputStream, options: Options) = true

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun decode(source: InputStream, width: Int, height: Int, options: Options): Resource<SVG>? {
        return try {
            val svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(source)
            SimpleResource(svg)
        } catch (ex: SVGParseException) {
            throw IOException("Cannot load SVG from stream", ex)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class SvgDrawableTranscoder : ResourceTranscoder<SVG?, PictureDrawable> {
    override fun transcode(toTranscode: Resource<SVG?>, options: Options): Resource<PictureDrawable>? {
        val svg = toTranscode.get()
        val picture = svg.renderToPicture()
        val drawable = PictureDrawable(picture)
        return SimpleResource(drawable)
    }
}
```

I also have this example project at https://github.com/hanscappelle/android-glide-svg-example and some more information on the required steps in my answer to this SO question [android how to load SVG into imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74627276/android-how-to-load-svg-into-imageview/78073150#78073150)

### Next steps

If you're looking at the latest example project from `Glide` there is some size handling added that can cause issues with `scaleType` set to your image view. For that look here [Image size too small when loading SVG with Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512975/image-size-too-small-when-loading-svg-with-glide?rq=3)

You probably also want to look into caching and other configuration options, see this info from Glide as a starting point https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html